# Regex to move return value to function parameter

Tags: regex

I have many lines like the following one:

```
PlayerInfo[playerid][pValue] = cache_get_value_name_int(i, "field");
```

However, due to library changes, I am now needed to replace this line with the following:

```
cache_get_value_name_int(i, "field", PlayerInfo[playerid][pValue]);
```

The problem is that PlayerInfo[playerid][pValue] is the "word" that changes. Every other line replaces this. Same things happens with "field".

I have a lot of lines which need replacing, at least a couple of hundreds of lines, so I want to find some sort of regex to replace them easily.

Any solutions for this?

Comment: What are you planning on using to do the change?

Comment: Notepad++ I guess

Comment: Well a simple global search and replace should suffice match the first line and replace with the second

Comment: all lines are different, like PlayerInfo[playerid][pValue] can be any other variable, like "foo". That s why I requested a Regex

Comment: OK can you update your question to make that more explicet

Comment: Well to get you started, in N++ `(...)` are used for capture groups, `\#` is used to reference a capture in the replace with box (`\1` for first, `\2` for second, and so on)

Comment: Will do in a sec

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Notepad++ you can use this regex:

```
([^\s]+) = cache_get_value_name_int\(i,\s*("[^"]+")\s*\);
```

It searches for some number of non-space characters (captured as group 1), followed by `=` (you might want to use `\s*=\s*` if spacing can vary), followed by `cache_get_value_name_int(i,`, a string enclosed in `"` (captured as group 2) and then a trailing `)` and `;`.

and replace it with

```
cache_get_value_name_int\(i, $2, $1\);
```

Note that you may need to add `\s*` in places to account for different spacing.

If the value `i` can also change, you can use this regex which captures that string as well:

```
([^\s]+) = cache_get_value_name_int\((\w+),\s*("[^"]+")\s*\);
```

and replace it with:

```
cache_get_value_name_int\($2, $3, $1\);
```

Answer (score 1):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^(\S+) = (cache_get_value_name_int\(\w+, "\w+")`
- Replace with: `$2, $1`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^                               # beginning of line
  (\S+)                         # group 1, 1 or more non space characters
   =                            # space, equal sign, space
  (                             # start group 2
    cache_get_value_name_int\(  # literally
    \w+                         # 1 or more word characters
    ,                           # comma, space
    "\w+"                       # 1 or more word characters surrounded with quotes
  )                             # end group 2
```

**Replacement:**

```
$2          # content of group 2
,           # comma & space
$1          # content of group 1
```

**Result for given example:**

```
cache_get_value_name_int(i, "field", PlayerInfo[playerid][pValue]);
```

---

**Screen capture:**

[image]